# CSS issues in IE only

Tags: css, wordpress

I've a page: http://volumee.dk/

everything is aligned to the left in IE only - what is the reason??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page is using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which causes IE to pretend to be IE5.5.

The reason this is happening to you is detailed here: [divs appearing different on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168612/divs-appearing-different-on-different-browsers/6168758#6168758)

> The reason you're getting Quirks Mode
>   is the two [UTF-8 byte order
>   marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
>   at the start of your file:
>
> ```
> ef bb bf ef bb bf 3c 21 44 4f 43
> .  .  .  .  .  .  <  !  D  O  C
> ```
>
> You'll need to save your file without
>   this. It should be an option in
>   whatever editor you're using.

Comment: Last version of header.php was sabed using Notepad... can this be a reason?

Comment: Try using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and on the "Encoding" menu pick "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM", then save your file. And listen to @songdogtech - you need to check multiple files. There are probably two files with this problem.

Comment: THANKS! I've saved it without "BOM" and it's Ok now :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the text encoding of index.php - and probably other theme files - to Unicode no-BOM. "The Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM) in UTF-8 encoded files is known to cause problems for some text editors and older browsers. You may want to consider avoiding its use until it is better supported."

2) Fix the code errors - the table errors are the most important - as those will give display problems in some browsers, like IE.[[Invalid] Markup Validation of  volumee.dk  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//volumee.dk/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

3) Try not to use a meta tag like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` and get your site to mostly valid xhtml and css for best results in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your header:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`
it might help, it makes newer versions of IE use their most up-to-date rendering capabilities.